# Excel – Matching cells value

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'd like to know how to do the following.

What I'm trying to do is get a value when two cells match, for example if "A1=b and B1=b then G1 should be "1" and if they don't match it should be "0". Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

What you are looking to do is combine the `IF` and the `AND` functions. These will allow you to perform logical checks, meet criteria then give a value depending if the criteria is met.

`IF(logical_test, [value_if_true], [value_if_false])` [source](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/if-function-HP010342586.aspx)

`AND(logical1, [logical2], ...)` [source](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/and-function-HP010069828.aspx)

In your case, you could use the following to get started.

```
=IF(AND(A1="b", B1="b"), 1,0)
```

Answer (score 3):

Another was to go about this would be to put in cell `C1`

```
=(A1="a")*(B1="b")
```

`Excel` evaluates each statement, and returns `TRUE` or `FALSE` accordingly. Then multiplying logical values gives numerical results (either `0`, if any of the two is `FALSE` or `1`, if both are `TRUE`).

I have found this technique useful to know, as it can help in more complex situations.

Answer (score 1):

> What I'm trying to do is get a value ***when two cells match***,
>   for example if A1=b and B1=b then …

This seems to be saying “if `A1` and `B1` are equal to the same value”,
i.e., “if `A1` and `B1` are equal *to each other*”. 
The other answers seem to be interpreting the question as
“if `A1` and `B1` are ***both*** equal to some *specified* value”.

To test whether `A1` matches `B1` and return a “1” if they do
and a “0” if they don’t, all you need to do is enter

```
=A1=B1
```

into the cell where you want the result (e.g., `G1`).
This works because “1” and “0” are the numeric values of `TRUE` and `FALSE`,
respectively, in Excel. 
If you wanted other values — for example, “42” if they match
and “−1” if they don’t — you can use an `IF` function:

```
=IF(A1=B1, 42, -1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your two cell values are in cells A1 and B1,enter =match(A1,B1,0) in cell C1. It will return 1 if there is a match.